# How can I make the underscore character letter-like/"inactive"?

Tags: verbatim, catcodes, underscore

I want to write some text - not within a `\verb` - in which underscores can appear and will be treated just like the letters. This requires some low-level TeX magic which I don't know - maybe something like `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`? Anyway, can someone help me with the appropriate snippet? An environment for doing this would be nice, but a starting and ending command for this state is also ok.

Comment: Well, don’t forget that you can always use `\_`… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: That's exactly what I want to forget. Think "copy-pasting".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's sufficient to change the catcode of `_` from `8`  into 'letter', i.e. `11`.

If it is done inside a group such as provided by an environment, the catcode change does not leak outside.

In order to make in a macro work, the cat code has to be change before the macro argument is read, i.e. this is a job for moving arguments actually, see the `\inactive` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newenvironment{inact}{%
  \catcode`\_11%
}{%
}


\newcommand{\inactive}{\begingroup\catcode`\_11 \inactiveinternal}%

\newcommand{\inactiveinternal}[1]{%
  #1\endgroup%
}



\begin{document}
\begin{inact}
Some stuff with_underline_characters
\end{inact}

\inactive{Use this with nice _ characters}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also mention what the catcode of an underscore is, normally? Also, does the 11 really need to be "hard-coded" like that? Also, if I put the `\catcode` command in a brace-group - is that enough to avoid the leak?

Comment: The catcode `11` for letter is hardcoded in `\makeatletter` as well. I don't think this will ever change or it would break TeX etc. It will work in `{...}` pair as well

Comment: @einpoklum what would you expect to use instead of a literal 11?  if you do not want `_` always to be `letter` but have interpretation depending on some other factor you can of course do that, but you asked for `_` to be like a letter, which is 11.

Comment: @einpoklum: Well, you can use one of the various verbatim packages as well. There's no need to do catcode 'hacks'. The approach above does not work for a command, however, since the catcodes of argument has been frozen already.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I would guess there might be some macro named `catcodeofletter` or something, and all these macros defined in the same place. But maybe that's impossible.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Awesome, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @einpoklum it's possible (`\chardef\catcodeofletter=11...\catcode\`\_=\catcodeofletter`) but doesn't really clarify much I think?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If it were used consistently in all TeX sources, it would make things clearer than setting catcodes to a literal number...

Comment: I would use 12 instead of 11 - in case that the underscore is behind some command.

Comment: @einpoklum: Knuth himself explains that “[he] has intentionally kept the category codes numeric instead of mnemonic, in order to discourage people from making extensive use of `\catcode` changes except in unusual circumstances” (_The TeXbook_, p. 48, eighth to sixth line from the bottom).